# write binary files in different directories after manipulating them?

Tags: r

I have 4 files as matrix 586 *1383 in one folder called list1 and other 4 files as matrix in another folder called list2(list1 and flist2 have the same dimensions).

I would like to filter files in  folder list1 based on files in  folder list2. So I want to replace values in files in  folder list2 by NA whenever corresponding files in  folder list1  pixels have values greater than 1000.

:Here are the files to download:

1- I tried this loop but when I wrote the results I got something weird which means that my loop is incorrect the results were files of size 1kb and not matrix (the right size should be something 3166kb).I am grateful to anyhelp to get my loop corrected.

```
dir1<- list.files("C:\\list1", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
dir2<- list.files("C:\\list2", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
 results<- list()
for (.files in seq_along(dir1)){
      list1 <- readBin(dir1[.files], numeric(), size = 4, n = 1383*586, signed = TRUE)   
      list2 <- readBin(dir2[.files], integer(), size = 2, n = 1383*586, signed = TRUE)                  
      results[[length(results) + 1L]]<- list1[list2 > 1000] <- NA}

     for (i in seq_along(results)){
     fileName <- sprintf("C:\\NewFile%03d.bin", i)
     writeBin(as.double(results[[i]]), fileName, size = 4)}
```

2- Can anybody tell me what code be wrong?

Comment: Your naming of `file1` for a folder made me tear my head for a while! :) ("files in folder file1 based on files in folder file2")

Comment: @Arun edited accordingly

Comment: No, it's alright. It just took me a while to get it. And it made me smile when I read the line I quoted... :)

Comment: sorry, but why is there a `}` at the end of the line where you load `list2`?

Comment: Sorry to have confused you.by mistake I put it there

Comment: your problem is the line `results[[.]] <- list1[.] <- NA`. This assigns `NA` to `list1[list2>1000]` **and** `results[[.]]`. Break those lines as: `list1[list2 > 1000] <- NA` and `results[[.]] <- list1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, the problem is with the line:

```
results[[length(results) + 1L]]<- list1[list2 > 1000] <- NA
```

This line assigns `NA` to `list1[list2 > 1000]` **and** `results[[length(results) + 1L]]`. I would break them to two lines like this:

```
list1[list2 > 1000] <- NA
results[[length(results) + 1L]] <- list1
```

Also, a suggestion. It is not wise to let your list "grow" every time. Since you already know the size of the list, it is better to allocate them in `results` **before** the for-loop. Because, if not, every time you assign `results[[length(results) + 1]]`, it will copy the entire object to create another element and it will be terribly slow as the list gets longer. So, to implement it would be something like:

```
results <- vector("list", length(dir1)) # create list with required size ( values set to NULL)
> length(results)
# [1] 4

for( i in seq_along(dir1)) {
    # load list1
    # load list2
    # assign NA
    results[[i]] <- list1 # assign using index i, all values of i exists, 
                          # as they are already assigned.
}
```